# First 'find' call does not return associated data. Second 'find' call does

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.1

The following is declared in model 'GradingPeriod':

```
class GradingPeriod extends AppModel {

   public $belongsTo = array('AcademicYear' => array('className' => 'AcademicYear', 'foreignKey' => 'academic_year_id'));

   ...

   public function getEnrolledSections(){

      $this->recursive = 1;

      debug($this->findById(21)); // Does **not** return AcademicYear
                                  // model data when function is called 
                                  // from a different model.

      debug($this->findById(21)); // **Does** return AcademicYear
                                  // model data when function is called  
                                  // from a different model.

      die();
   }
}
```

When called from a controller or inside the GradingPeriod model, this works fine. The first 'find' call **does** return the GradingPeriod model's associated data (AcademicYear).

When called from a **different model**, the first 'find' call **does not** return the GradingPeriod model's associated data (AcademicYear). The second 'find' call **does** return the GradingPeriod model's associated data (AcademicYear).

```
class ReportCard extends AppModel {

   public function callToGradingPeriod(){

      $objGradingPeriod = ClassRegistry::init('GradingPeriod');

      $objGradingPeriod->getEnrolledSections();

   }

}
```

I have tried this with CakePHP 2.1.2 and 2.2.3 with the same results.

I know calling one model from another may be considered bad form, but why is this code behaving as it does? Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Try `debug($this->recursive);` just before each `findById()`

Comment: Debug returned `1` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer as far as why it's working (or not) the way it is, but a suggestion for you and any future users trying something similar:

Don't EVER use `recursive` to get associated data.  Set `public $recursive = -1;` in your AppModel and never look back. When you want related data, use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

It might seem like recursive is your friend - or that it's "just easier", but I promise it will cause issues further down the road - either when you want more data, or just when you get more data in your database (memory issues/errors among other things).  It's bad practice, and I believe they're even going to remove recursive all together in CakePHP 3+.

Trust me on this one - ditch recursive, and use `contain()` instead.

Comment: Yes, using `Containable` is a must, but this problem is still a mystery. :D 
@Rob if the DB you're using is MySQL could you try: 
`$this->ModelName->query("COUNT(1)");`
Execute this before the first find and see if things change.
As crazy as this sounds, this will rebuild the index of the DB. :D
I have a little suspicion that this may help. This could help if you have an enormous DB.

Comment: Thank you. Very good advise. Before posting, I actually tried `Containable` before the simple finds with the same result. I just used the simple finds in the question for clarity. I should have been more granular in my question. Unfortunately, the above suggestions did not work.